# E2E testing on angularjs using protractor yielding different results between running a single test file and all test files

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I am using protractor to do E2E testing on an angularjs application.  I started with the angular-seed base project which comes with npm set up to run all of your e2e tests with the command npm run protractor, which really just runs "protractor test/protractor-conf.js". I have a test that goes to a page, selects a dropdown menu item, and then verifies that the resulting

```
it('should render all of the available '+subsystem.subsystem_name+' that can be created', function() {
```

//                    first select the appropriate subsystem from the dropdown

```
                element(by.cssContainingText('.subsystem_select option', subsystem.subsystem_name)).click().then(function(){
                    var create_table = element.all(by.css('table')).get(0);
//                  filter the General Options and check that the Option Create Table is rendered correctly
                    browser.executeScript(function(ms_valid_options,subsystem_id) {
                        return angular.element(document).injector().get("$filter")("filter")(ms_valid_options, {subsystem_id:subsystem_id})
                    }, MS_VALID_OPTIONS, subsystem.subsystem_id).then(function(filtered_options){
                        expect( element.all(by.repeater('option in valid_options')).count() ).toEqual(filtered_options.length);
                        filtered_options.forEach(function(valid_option,i){
                            var current_row = element.all(by.repeater('option in valid_options')).get(i);
                            expect( current_row.all(by.css('td')).get(0).getText() ).toEqual(valid_option.option_name+"("+valid_option.default_value+")"); //first table cell has text option_name(default_value)
                            expect( current_row.all(by.css('td')).get(1).getInnerHtml() ).toEqual('<input type="button" value="Add Option" ng-click="addOption(option)">')//second table cell contains the add option button
                            expect( current_row.all(by.css('td')).get(2).all(by.css('span')).get(0).getText() ).toEqual('?');//third table cell contains the help questionmark
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
```

when I run the individual test file all the tests pass as expected, but when I run all of the test files with the npm run protractor command, this test is failing with the error

TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'all'
and this error is complaining about the line

```
expect( current_row.all(by.css('td')).get(0).getText() ).toEqual(valid_option.option_name+"("+valid_option.default_value+")");
```

Any insight into this issue would be appreciated

Thanks

*edit*
just a bit more information, when running the single file(successful case) current_row is an object with these keys on it
 [ 'locator_',
  'parentElementFinder_',
  'opt_actionResult_',
  'opt_index_',
  'click',
  'sendKeys',
  'getTagName',
  'getCssValue',
  'getAttribute',
  'getText',
  'getSize',
  'getLocation',
  'isEnabled',
  'isSelected',
  'submit',
  'clear',
  'isDisplayed',
  'getOuterHtml',
  'getInnerHtml',
  'toWireValue' ]

and when the test is run along with all the other tests(failure case) current_row is an object with these keys on it
[ 'then',
  'cancel',
  'isPending',
  'errback',
  'driver_',
  'id_',
  'click',
  'sendKeys',
  'getTagName',
  'getCssValue',
  'getAttribute',
  'getText',
  'getSize',
  'getLocation',
  'isEnabled',
  'isSelected',
  'submit',
  'clear',
  'isDisplayed',
  'getOuterHtml',
  'getInnerHtml',
  'toWireValue',
  '$',
  'findElement',
  '$$',
  'findElements',
  'isElementPresent',
  'evaluate' ]

Comment: just a bit more information, when running the single file(successful case) current_row is an object with these keys on it [ 'locator_',
  'parentElementFinder_',
  'opt_actionResult_',
  'opt_index_',
  'click',
  'sendKeys',
  'getTagName',
  'getCssValue',
  'getAttribute',
  'getText',
  'getSize',
  'getLocation',
  'isEnabled',
  'isSelected',
  'submit',
  'clear',
  'isDisplayed',
  'getOuterHtml',
  'getInnerHtml',
  'toWireValue' ]

Answer (score 0):

I have had issues with tests interfering with one another, which may be the case here.  I basically just had to make sure I was in the correct state after each of my tests by doing logouts in an afterEach(), and starting from login for each test, or related set of tests.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would make use of a PageObject (po) to make the tests more readable. So for example you could include initially:

```
var poSubsystem = {}, option1Text='..';
poSubsystem.table = element(by.tagName('table')).first();
poSubsystem.options = poSubsystem.table.all(by.tagName('td'));
poSubsystem.option1 = poSubsystem.options.first();
// .etc
expect(poSubsystem.option1.getText()).toEqual(option1Text);
```

By the time you've tidied things up the answer should have made itself known :-)